# combining two api json response using wso2 developer studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I can't seem to find a way to combine two api json response by using wso developer studio. I'm still reading their documentation and i found that there is a mediator called aggregate mediator but i can't seem cant to find a way to combine the api calls and map it all while using the wso developer studio. So for example Google Contacts and Fullcontact api combines the response

Answer (score 0):

In aggregate mediator, you can not aggregate responses coming from different services. When you are using aggregate mediator you have to use it with clone/iterate mediators. Those mediators will send identical clones/ chunks of message to different endpoints. Those responses will be gathered by aggregate mediator.

In your scenario, you have to use Service Chaining pattern in ESB. Please refer WSO2 documentation [1] and this blog post series [2] will help you to implement your scenario.

You can implement this pattern using developer studio. Just identify what are the components (Ex: Proxy) you need and implement them through Dev Studio.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Service+Chaining+Example

[2] http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2012/06/routing-and-service-chaining-with-wso2.html

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to recommend the mediators that you should use, without knowing exact use case. [Scatter-Gather](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Scatter-Gather) pattern with clone and aggregate mediators would be fine if your services are independent(one does not require other's output as input).

If they are dependent, invoke the first one using  mediator and you may use a property mediator to remember the output. After the second call, you can combine them using a [Payload Factory](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/PayloadFactory+Mediator) mediator or, if it is a complex integration, you may use [XSLT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/XSLT+Mediator) mediator.